# How to have a top vertical alignment in tabularx when including images?

Tags: tables, tabularx, includegraphics

I would like to include previews in a table and force the text to either be centered or top aligned. How can I achieve this without redefining the X column for the whole document?

Here my MRE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\IfFileExists{4D5GD.png}{}{\write18{wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D5GD.png}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXr}
\toprule
\textbf{Overview} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Hyperlink} \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{4D5GD.png} & Lorem Ipsum & 
\href{ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/4D5GD.png}{Link} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With moving image baseline by help of `adjustbox` package to top of image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\IfFileExists{4D5GD.png}{}{\write18{wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D5GD.png}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXr}
\toprule
\textbf{Overview} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Hyperlink} \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=t]{example-image-duck}%{4D5GD.png} 
    & Lorem Ipsum & \href{ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/4D5GD.png}{Link} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However by use `tblr` table as defined in `tabularray` package the moving image baseline is not needed any more, so you can use `graphicx` package instead `adjustbox. Beside this, the result of compilation is nicer from before:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\IfFileExists{4D5GD.png}{}{\write18{wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D5GD.png}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c,h] X[h] Q[r,h]}}
\toprule
\textbf{Overview} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Hyperlink} \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[height=2cm, valign=t]{example-image-duck}%{4D5GD.png} 
    & Lorem Ipsum & \href{ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/4D5GD.png}{Link} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```